# Replace specific word between characters using sed?

Tags: regex, sed

Does anyone know how to replace specific words between `()`.  So, for example, replace the word `and` with `or` in between both sets of parentheseis:

> (grade='C' and grade='D' and grade='E') and (int_rate>=10 and int_rate<=20) and pub_rec>=0 
>       and term=' 36 months'

This would be:

> (grade='C' **or** grade='D' **or** grade='E') and (int_rate>=10 **or** int_rate<=20) and pub_rec>=0 
>       and term=' 36 months'

Comment: Can this even be done with a single regular expression?

Answer (score 1):

Really dorky approach:

```
$ sed 's/and/or/g' INPUT | sed 's/) or (/) and (/' | sed 's/\(.*\)or/\1and/'
(grade='C' or grade='D' or grade='E') and (int_rate>=10 or int_rate<=20) and pub_rec>=0 
and term=' 36 months'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/\band\b([^()]*\))/or\1/;ta' file
```

Work backwards throught the file changing `and`'s within `(...)` to `or`'s.

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$_ ="(grade='C' and grade='D' and grade='E') and (int_rate>=10 and int_rate<=20) and pub_rec>=0 and term=' 36 months'";
print "Before: $_\n";

while (/(\([^\)]+?)and(.+?\))/) {
    s/(\([^\)]+?)and(.+?\))/$1or$2/g;
}
print "After: $_\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought about it a bit more and came up with this solution:

```
$ sed "s/(/\n(/g" | sed "s/)/)\n/g" | sed "/(/s/and/or/g" | tr '\n' '!' | sed "s/!//g"
(grade='C' or grade='D' or grade='E') and (int_rate>=10 or int_rate<=20) and pub_rec>=0 and term=' 36 months'
```

Basically, broke up content in multiple lines with with separator as parenthesis, use sed on all lines with parenthesis to convert all ands to ors, then bring back all into single line.

Comment: It throws following error to me: `bash: !//g": event not found`. I think `!` is a reserved word and `bash` would try to interpolate it inside double quotes. I surrounded that last `sed` command with single quotes and then is interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

One solution using [vim](/questions/tagged/vim)

Content of **script.vim**

```
set backup
while search( ')', 'W' ) > 0 
    execute "normal vi)\<ESC>"
    '<,'>s/\v%V<and>/or/ge
    call cursor( line('.'), col('.') + 2 )
endwhile
normal ZZ
```

Run it like:

```
vim -S script.vim infile
```

That updates the file in-place with following result.

```
(grade='C' or grade='D' or grade='E') and (int_rate>=10 or int_rate<=20) and pub_rec>=0 and term=' 36 months'
```

Also creates a backup file appending the `~` suffix to the original file name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Sed, but here is a regexp that matches only `and` if followed by a `)`:

```
\band\b(?=[^(]*\))
```

Simply replace the matches by `or` just as [this demo](http://regexr.com?35412).

---

Side note: this won't check the syntax of the input, i.e. the number of parentheses, etc. If you intend to do so, maybe some existing parsers could suit your needs.